# Checkin API broken?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, checkin

I'm getting checkins from the facebook API in a iOS-app. This worked perfectly earlier, but now I always get this response with an empty array. Has the API changed or something?

reponse:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Comment: Do you definitely have a) the right permissions, and b) a user with recent checkins? A user can subsequently remove an app's permission to view certain data so maybe that happened in your case

Comment: Yeah, as I said, this worked for a few days ago, and it worked for a lot of testers of our app, no problems at all, havent changed any of the code, and now it just returns the empty array. Have ckeched that we got the correct permissions, and we do.

Comment: I mean, do they actually have any checkins? If they do, this is likely a bug - file it at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: I just tested the iPad App, it doesnt show any checkins either, but my iphone app does show checkins (4 from within the last 24h, and 15 totally).

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue using the Graph API Explorer tool?

Comment: This affects my app too. I didn't see a bug report, so I posted one: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/242601885831384. If anybody found a work-around for searching for friend's checkins, any hints would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook had an issue, they have fixed it now.